# Sql to find character on the string

Tags: sql, substring, charindex

I have string as shown, I need to get value next to "INTERNAL_INSTRUCTION_NUM" means i need to get value "9076" means in my table INTERNAL_INSTURCTION_NUM having value 9076. i need to retrieve from string. put inside the asterisk is the one i required from string. i need to pass parameter as INTERNAL_INSTURCTION_NUM and value returned as "9076"

String attached in below link.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BypBdg0gwa3Bb3FlakFVY29QTGc

Comment: unable to attach the string. Use the below dropbox for the string attached text file.

Comment: Seems like a product specific issue. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Answer (score 0):

This is a **SQL Server** version:

```
declare @param nvarchar(max) = N'INTERNAL_INSTRUCTION_NUM';

declare 
    @pos int,
    @temp nvarchar(max);

set @pos = charindex(@param, @test);

set @temp = substring(@test, @pos + len(@param), len(@test) 
                 - @pos - len(@param));

-- find first # after param
set @pos = charindex('#', @temp);
set @temp = substring(@temp, @pos+1, len(@temp) - @pos);

-- find second # after param
set @pos = charindex('#', @temp);
set @temp = substring(@temp, @pos+1, len(@temp) - @pos);

-- find the value we are looking for assuming it is enclosed between ",+" and "?%"
select substring(@temp, 3, len(@temp) - 4)
```